# Can't load angular 2 modules into router when using system.js

Tags: angular, systemjs

I hope someone can help because I had spent a lot of hours on this and can't figure this out...
I used to use system.js with the following syntax:

```
   System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  packages: {
    //'component': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}
    'src': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}
  },
  typescriptOptions: {emitDecoratorMetadata: true}
});
System.import('./component/App.ts');
```

and now I wanted to convert to the syntax using pure js extension and to map my node_modules dir so I am using:

```
  System.config({
      packages: {
        'src': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
      },
      "defaultJSExtensions": true,
      "paths": {
        "bootstrap": "/src/",
        "src/*": "src/*",
        "*": "/node_modules/*"
      }
    })
```

and now none of my Routes in my router are loading.
Now, I confirmed that if I copy and paste a module into the same file as my router config all is well.. so I know what you are thinking, my path is wrong... but it's not. Angular CAN get to the modules. In fact if I rename something like

```
import {LoginPanel} from '/src/comps/entry/LoginPanel';
```

to

```
import {LoginPanel} from '/src/comps/entry/LoginPanelFOOBAR';
```

I will get an error with the FOOTBAR, so I know the paths are ok, but yet everytime I get the attached error using the new system.js JS config.

ANY HELP IS GREATLY appreciated.

tx

Sean

[image]

Comment: You dont't need to map paths in systemjs config and it's a bad idea to reference 'src' folder in imports .. check this out https://github.com/zouabimourad/angular2-spring/blob/master/front/src/index.html

Comment: thanks for the reply... but even if I keep my system.js as simple as  System.config({
          "baseURL": "/",
          "defaultJSExtensions": true
        })   still it's a no go ... :(

Comment: can you share the code source in plunker or somewhere else ?

Comment: yes thanks for looking into to this as I can't progress until I get this solved. I created a clean project on GitHub. You can see that if I include my HomeCmp component in my main file, all is great ... BUT if I comment HomeCmp and instead I import HomeCmp from an external module, everything blows up... TX AGAIN... here is the link on GitHub:   https://github.com/born2net/ng2RouterProblem

Comment: You can look at this file in particular https://github.com/born2net/ng2RouterProblem/blob/master/app/bootstrap.ts

Comment: I will even send you a paypal tip as a token of my appreciation in solving this... tx

Comment: well I think I found the issue, I compiled with -target es6 and now changed to -target es5 and all works... woooff.... 5 hours on this one, hopefully it helps someone else...!

Comment: i fixed the problems in https://github.com/zouabimourad/ng2RouterProblem ( there were other issues beside es6 )